# how does the method of partial fraction decomposition by long division works when there is repeated root?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

I am reading
[A treatise on integral calculus](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonintegr01edwauoft)
and I can't understand what does the author means here,
how does $\frac{y^2+2y+1}{y+2}$ turned into $0.5 +0.75y+0.125y^2-\frac{y^3}{8(2+y)}$

and I didn't understand the whole method

[image]

Comment: What they are doing is long division with reverse degree monomial order. This is, you do  long division, but consider a term larger when its degree is smaller. Remember that in long division you always divide leading term by leading term. Here is the same, but leading means lowest degree. So, they divide $1+2y+y^2$ by $2+y$. This gives the series in powers of $y$ of $\frac{1+2y+y^2}{2+y}$. Since they plan to divide later by $y^3$, and keep only the terms with negative exponents, the long division only needs to be carried until the terms of the quotient become larger than degree $3$.

Comment: By the way, what is the book (title and author(s))?

Comment: @NDB Atreatise on integral calculus https://archive.org/details/treatiseonintegr01edwauoft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original fraction is given by the following:

$$
\frac{\left(y+1\right)^{2}}{y^{3}\cdot(y+2)}
$$

This is a ratio between a quadratic polynomial (which is simply a cubic polynomial with first coefficient zero) and a polynomial of order $4$. There are many ways to express a cubic polynomial, two examples are given below:

$$
\begin{aligned}
p\left(y\right)
&=
ay^{3}+by^{2}+cy+d
\\
p\left(y\right)
&=
A\left(y+2\right)+By\left(y+2\right)+Cy^{2}\left(y+2\right)+Dy^{3}
\end{aligned}
$$

Using both expression, our numerator is given by the followings, respectively:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(y+1\right)^{2}
&=
y^{2}+2y+1
\\
\left(y+1\right)^{2}
&=\frac{y+2}{2}+\frac{3y\left(y+2\right)}{4}+\frac{y^{2}\left(y+2\right)}{8}-\frac{y^{3}}{8}
\end{aligned}
$$

Substitute back to the original equation to obtain the desired result.

**Key Points**

- There are more than one way to express a polynomial
- Choose numerator expression that can cancel terms in the denominator, in our case $y^{3}$ and $y+2$

Comment: thank you very much , but there one thing that I don't understand yet which is what is the steps of long division that the author does , I can reduce it by adding and subtracting which is clearly not the easiest way

Comment: @pie When dividing $\frac{1+2y+y^2}{2+y}$, you divide the leading terms first (leading meaning lowest degree). So, $\frac{1}{2}$. Then take this newly added term of the quotient and multiply it by the divisor and subtract the result from the dividend $1+2y+y^2 - \frac{1}{2}(2+y)=\frac{3}{2}y+y^2$. Now you repeat. The leading terms are now $\frac{3}{2}y$ and $2$. Divide them and $\frac{3}{4}y$ is the next term for the quotient. You can go on forever, but for this application only one more iteration is needed.